# Scale watermark overlay by video size with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark, overlay

I would like to scale a watermark to 5% of the video width.

I need something like that:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v] scale=1_MP4_VIDEO_WIDTH*0.05:-1 [logo1]; [0:v][logo1] overlay=0:0" -y -b 1600k -c:v libx264 -profile high -level 4.1 -c:a libfaac -q:a 128k 2.mp4
```

How can I reference the video width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a linux environment (or cygwin on windows), the only way I found is to execute 2 commands.

First to get main video size and perform math on them (note: `x/20 == x*0.05`:

```
val=`ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mp4 2>&1 | grep Video: | sed 's_.*, \([0-9]*x[0-9]*\) .*_\1_' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="x"} {print int($1/20)"x"int($2/20)}'`
```

Second to scale and overlay the video

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v] scale=$val [logo1]; [0:v][logo1] overlay=0:0" -y -b 1600k -c:v libx264 -profile high -level 4.1 -c:a libfaac -q:a 128k 2.mp4
```

Also, you could just replace `$val` on second line with the first expression (including backquotes) and get the same result, but I find it a little easier to read splitting command in two.

Comment: Because it seems that there is no other soultion, I accept yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This can now be performed directly using the `scale2ref` filter.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw*0.05:-1[logo1][base]; \
 [base][logo1]overlay=0:0[v]" \
-map [v] -map 0:a -y -b:v 1600k -c:v libx264 -profile high -level 4.1 \
-c:a libfaac -b:a 128k 2.mp4
```

Comment: Hey, your command work and thanks, but it doesn't maintain the aspect ratio of watermark, it stretch it to the video size. How to fix it ?

Comment: @EmadGhasemi if u want aspect ratio. firstly you have to calculate watermark ratio(height/width). Then change this [1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw*0.05:(iw*0.05)*watermark_ratio[logo1][base]

Comment: See my comment in this answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1100429/85904

You can now do this with one command

Comment: I am getting 45 mb video which is previously 5 mb

Comment: @PratikButani that has been my issue. When I try to use the scale2ref it makes the file size much bigger. I don't know if that is a bug or it's not used correctly. Gyan any insight?

Comment: Ask new Q with full command AND logs

Answer (score 1):

As for Windows, I discovered following method using ffprobe and ffmpeg. Here is a .bat file code:

```
@echo off
   SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

   for %%a in ("*.mp4") do (
      For /F "usebackq" %%I In (`ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream"="width -of default"="noprint_wrappers"="1:nokey"="1 "%%~a"`) Do (

      Set V=%%~I
      ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i logo.png -b:v 1M -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=(SCALE_FACTOR*!V!):-1 [wm]; [0:v][wm] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h)" -y -v 2 "new\%%~na.mp4"
)
```

)

Here SLACE_FACTOR is overlay image width divided to some reference video file width (for ex., 320px/1280px).

Comment: I don't think the left and right parentheses match in the code.